# Using toString() as a hack to generate keys for react-select component

Tags: javascript, react.js

While trying to integrate [react-select](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select) component on my codebase on documentation it's explained that you can pass an array of `options` with **label** and **value** attributes eg :

```
import Select from 'react-select';

let options = [
 {
  label: 'Color',
  value: 'Blue'
 }
]

<Select options={options} />
```

And it works fine, but in my case I need **value** to be an object as simply a `String` won't do the job how I want. I know I can keep an array of objects separately and do a find based on their ID on that array but this lacks on performance and increases chances for side effects.

So what I tried was using options with value as objects :

```
let options = [
  {
    label: 'Color',
    value: {
      r: 123,
      g: 78,
      b: 198
    }
  }
]
```

But this way I had errors on my console, telling me that you have to use unique keys for each child and this was because the component takes an option value and uses that for key and that key when converted to string became "`[object Object]`" so finally the key was always `option-[object Object]` .

To solve this out I overrode the **value** attribute `toString()` method and it worked :

```
let options = [
  {
    label: 'Color',
    value: {
      r: 123,
      g: 78,
      b: 198,
      toString: function(){
        return this.r + this.g + this.b;
      }
    }
  }
]
```

So what could be downsides of this, as obviously this is a hack.

Comment: Not your typical CR question, but I'm intrigued by the format of it. ++ Welcome to Code Review.

Answer (score 1):

One possible down-site of this could be a performance issue and this depends on how `toString()` is implemented.

On my case I did it like this :

```
let options = [
  {
    label: 'Color',
    value: {
      r: 123,
      g: 78,
      b: 198,
      toString: function(){
        return uuid.v1();
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Whenever the state or props are updated React uses a diff. algorithm to check if it's **VirtualDOM** and **DOM** corresponds, which means every time React looped through options they had a different key value and React re-rendered every option no matter if their value changed or not.

In my case a fix was to hash the value object using [this](https://github.com/puleos/object-hash) library;

```
let options = [
  {
    label: 'Color',
    value: {
      r: 123,
      g: 78,
      b: 198,
      toString: function(){
        return hash(this);
      }
    }
  }
]
```